# Does this property hold for a Geometric Brownian Motion?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, limsup-and-liminf

Assume that $B_t$ is a Brownian motion. Let $\mu, \sigma$ be real numbers greater than zero. Do we then have

$$P\left(\liminf\limits_{t\rightarrow \infty}e^{\mu t+\sigma B_t}>1\right)=1?$$

I am not sure how to start to figure this out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, in fact $\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} e^{\mu t + \sigma B_t} = \infty$ almost surely.  We can show $\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \frac{B_t}{t} = 0$ a.s. so $$\mu t + \sigma B_t = t\left(\mu + \sigma \frac{B_t}{t}\right)$$ converges to $\infty$ almost surely (since $\mu > 0$).  This implies $\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} e^{\mu t + \sigma B_t} = \infty$ a.s. and in particular $$P\left( \liminf_{t \rightarrow \infty} e^{\mu t + \sigma B_t} > 1 \right) = 1.$$

Comment: Thank you, but how do you show $\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \frac{B_t}{t} = 0$ a.s.?

Comment: @user394334 $B_t \sim \mathcal{N}(0, t)$.

Comment: @RiversMcForge The most I am able to prove using that is that for instance if we let $B_n$ be what the process is at time $n$ then the sequence converges to $0$ in probability, hence a subsequence $B_{n_k}/n_{k}$ converges to $0$ a.s. But I need that the enitre path eventually goes to zero.

Comment: The law of the iterated logarithm gives a pretty direct proof.  The reflection principle does too by showing $\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sup_{s \le t} B_s}{t} = 0$ a.s. and applying it to $B_t$ and $-B_t$.  Otherwise you can use time inversion ($t B_{1/t}$ is a Brownian motion, so $P(\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \frac {B_t}t = 0) = P(\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \frac{t B_{1/t}}{t} = 0) = P(\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} B_{1/t} = 0) = 1$.)